# FreeMarker : Displaying a custom 404 page without redirection

Tags: java, servlets, freemarker

I have a static 404 page with fancy stuff in it. 
In case the user enters a wrong url of a page that does not exist, I would like him to see that 404 page , but also would like to keep the url as is in order for user to see what mistake s/he has done typing the url .

**The page entered and that does not exist  :**
http://localhost:10039/my.website/my/halp.html

**The 404 page :** 
http://localhost:10039/my.website/my/notfound.html

Briefly, instead of using "sendRedirect" here, I would to "get content" of pageNotFoundUrl and show it while the url is still http://localhost:10039/my.website/my/halp.html

Instead of redirect, I also tried "forward" as Kayaman suggested but in this case I get **" Cannot forward. Response already committed."**

TestServlet is defined in web.xml , and this class extends UtilFreemarkerServlet which extends FreemarkerServlet.

**UtilFreemarkerServlet**

```
public abstract class UtilFreemarkerServlet extends FreemarkerServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String REQUEST_OBJECT_NAME = "RequestObject";

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        logger.info("init started");
        super.init();
        Configuration cfg = getConfiguration();
        cfg.setLocalizedLookup(false);

    }

    @Override
    protected ObjectWrapper createObjectWrapper() {
        return ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER;
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpRequestParametersHashModel createRequestParametersHashModel(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute(REQUEST_OBJECT_NAME, request);
        return super.createRequestParametersHashModel(request);
    }   

}
```

**TestServlet**

```
public class TestServlet extends UtilFreemarkerServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private String website;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {     
        super.service(req, resp);       
        boolean handleResult = handlerForRequest(req, resp);            
    }

    protected boolean handlerForRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (resp.getStatus() == 404) {
            String pageNotFoundUrl = "http://localhost:10039/my.website/my/notfound.html";          
            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher(url);
            rd.forward(req, resp);
            // resp.sendRedirect(url);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use javascript to change the page content... and use the same page in which you are getting data from user...

Comment: @CoderNeji, not sure sure if I want to put JS in my project. Is this possible to handle them all on server side?

Comment: you can do all that at the server side but the url will change as the 404 page is there and you have set the 404 page as error page and it has some path for its fetching.

Comment: @shamaleyte Use forwarding instead of redirecting to keep the URL but show the 404 page's contents.

Comment: CoderNeji, then not possible without changing the url at server side?  

@Kayaman, how can I do the forwarding ?  by RequestDispatcher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RequestDispatcher is not useful in my case because the response has always been committed. Here is the solution I end up with for Freemarker Servlets;**

I am overriding a couple of methods of Freemarker servlet for my purpose such as service() and requestUrlToTemplatePath(). By this way, I am able to interfere right before the response is committed.

1. First Override is for the service method.  My purpose is to check if the requested url page exists or not.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {         
       checkIfPageExists(req);
       super.service(req, resp);                       
   }
   ```
2. checkIfPageTemplateExists checks if the template of the page is null or not. If null, then it means it is not available. In this case I set a request attribute. Otherwise, it means it exists.

   ```
   protected void checkIfPageExists(HttpServletRequest req)
   throws     ServletException {

   String relativeUrl = requestUrlToTemplatePath(req);
   try {
           getConfiguration().getTemplate(relativeUrl); //throws exception if the template cannot be accessed
       } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {
           logger.debug("TemplateNotFoundException for " + relativeUrl);
           pageNotFound = "/customNotFoundPage.html";
       } catch (IOException e) {
           logger.debug("IOException for " + relativeUrl);
           pageNotFound = "/customNotFoundPage.html";
       } 
     req.setAttribute(NOT_FOUND_PAGE, pageNotFoundPage);
   }
   ```
3. And the last line stated in bullet 1 is for super.service() method.  This will trigger the requestUrlToTemplatePath() method which is actually the method you can specify what url page to be shown without changing the url. 
   I am just checking if the request has a NOT_FOUND_PAGE attribute. If so, just overwrite the path itself and move on to the next step in the flow. Otherwise, just use the path of super class.

   ```
   @Override
   protected String requestUrlToTemplatePath(HttpServletRequest request) 
   throws ServletException {

       String path = super.requestUrlToTemplatePath(request);

       //Check if NOT_FOUND_PAGE is requested
       if(request.getAttribute(NOT_FOUND_PAGE) != null) {
           path =  (String) request.getAttribute(NOT_FOUND_PAGE);      
       }

    return path;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Do a forward instead of a redirect to the wanted resource, and the URL will stay the same.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my_404.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I get the following error "Cannot forward. Response already committed.".  Any way to make it before response is committed ?

Comment: You need to do that as soon as possible, before anything is done to the response object. Edit the question and show your code.